# GIF's loaded with JavaScript not animating in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, firefox

I am working on a page for a ruby project that allows the user to run multiple shell scripts at once from a web UI.  The entire page is a couple of input forms, and a bunch of check boxes for which scripts to run.  Beside each checkbox, there is a label and a status image (untouched [non-animated gif], loading [gif], success [png], fail [png]).  I have been testing in Firefox 51, and have no issues with anything.  But when I tried to use the page in Google Chrome, the images load fine, but the loading gif does not actually animate.  The way it is done is by replacing the image in the field using JavaScript.

**HTML**

```
<div class="span3">
  <%= check_box_tag(:mail_harvest, 1, false) %>
  <%= label_tag(:mail_harvest, "Mail Harvest (Google + AdobeLeaks)", :class => "checkbox inline") %>
    <img src="/assets/project/wait.gif" id="mail_harvest_img" style="width:16px; height:16px; float:right;"></img>
  <br />
  <%= check_box_tag(:file_harvest, 1, false) %>
  <%= label_tag(:file_harvest, "File Harvest", :class => "checkbox inline") %>
  <img src="/assets/project/wait.gif" id="file_harvest_img" style="width:16px; height:16px; float:right;"></img>
  <br />
...
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
if(document.getElementById("mail_harvest").checked == true)
{
  document.getElementById("mail_harvest_img").src = "/assets/project/loading.gif"
  results = $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "/console/discovery/mail_harvest",
    data: { domain_name : domainInput },
    success: function(data)
    {
      document.getElementById("mail_harvest_img").src = "/assets/project/Check16.png"
      //do some stuff
    },
    error: function(data)
    {
      document.getElementById("mail_harvest_img").src = "/assets/project/X16.png"
    },
  });
}//End of mail_harvest
```

Basically when you click the submit button, the page does not reload but the images for each tool selected will be replaced by the "loading" gif, and when the ajax call succeeds or fails, the image changes to a checkmark or an x.  This works perfectly fine in Firefox, and works mostly fine in Chrome (the check or x appears on success or fail) except for the loading gif.  Is this an issue with the browser, or am I missing something in my code?

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing how I was handling the photos.  Instead of changing the source of the image tag constantly, I chose to load all the images together on page load, with the loading, checkmark, and x all hidden.  When I need to change the image, I use jQuery to hide and show the images as needed

**HTML**

```
<div class="span3">
  <%= check_box_tag(:mail_harvest, 1, false) %>
  <%= label_tag(:mail_harvest, "Mail Harvest (Google + AdobeLeaks)", :class => "checkbox inline") %>
  <%= image_tag("project/wait.gif", :id => "mail_harvest_wait_img") %>
  <%= image_tag("project/loading.gif", :id => "mail_harvest_loading_img", :class => "hidden") %>
  <%= image_tag("project/Check16.png", :id => "mail_harvest_check_img", :class => "hidden") %>
  <%= image_tag("project/X16.png", :id => "mail_harvest_x_img", :class => "hidden") %>
  <br />
...
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
if(document.getElementById("mail_harvest").checked == true)
{
  $('#mail_harvest_wait_img').addClass('hidden');
  $('#mail_harvest_loading_img').removeClass('hidden');
  results = $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "/console/discovery/mail_harvest",
    data: { domain_name : domainInput },
    success: function(data)
    {
      $('#mail_harvest_loading_img').addClass('hidden');
      $('#mail_harvest_check_img').removeClass('hidden');
      //do some stuff
    },
    error: function(data)
    {
      $('#mail_harvest_loading_img').addClass('hidden');
      $('#mail_harvest_x_img').removeClass('hidden');
    },
  });
}//End of mail_harvest
```